# How to sort inner object while parsing json data with gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have two classes.

Class SubCategory

```
public class SubCategory implements Comparable<SubCategory>{

    private int scid;
    private String scname;

    public SubCategory(int scid, String scname) {
        this.scid = scid;
        this.scname = scname;
    }

    public int getScid() {
        return scid;
    }

    public void setScid(int scid) {
        this.scid = scid;
    }

    public String getScname() {
        return scname;
    }

    public void setScname(String scname) {
        this.scname = scname;
    }

    public int compareTo(SubCategory subCategory){
        return this.getScname().compareTo(subCategory.getScname());
    }

}
```

Class Category

```
public class Category implements Comparable<Category>{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String image;
    private int display_with;
    private List<SubCategory> subcategories;

    public Category(int id, String name, String image, int display_with, List<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.display_with = display_with;
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getDisplay_with() {
        return display_with;
    }

    public void setDisplay_with(int display_with) {
        this.display_with = display_with;
    }

    public List<SubCategory> getSubcategories() {
        return subcategories;
    }

    public void setSubcategories(List<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    public int compareTo(Category category){
        return this.getName().compareTo(category.getName());
    }

}
```

This is retrofir request.

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASERESTURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

I am Parsing the data with gson library in retrofit response

```
  public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<List<Category>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
      loading.dismiss();
      List<Category> categories = response.body();
      Collections.sort(categories);
      Utility.setCategories(categories);
  }
```

i can sort the categories with Collections.sort(categories);

But how to sort subcategories with category??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this right in setSubcategories, so everytime you set new subcategories they will get sorted:

```
public void setSubcategories(List<SubCategory> subcategories) {
    Collections.sort(subcategories)
    this.subcategories = subcategories;
}
```

Also you should replace `this.subcategories = subcategories;` with `this.setSubcategories(subcategories)` in your Constructor.